# Dock doesn't disappear before reboot

Tags: macos, dock, reboot

Every time when I'm trying to reboot my mac(macbook pro retina|el capitan), everything disappear except dock so the process stops and thats how my desktop looks:[image]

Comment: Try putting this in the terminal before rebooting: `sudo kill -9 $(pgrep Dock)`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please help us to answer your question by providing additional info such as the type of computer, the operating system version, any error messages, etc.  You can see this for how to ask good questions: [ask].

Comment: Looking at that picture, it's not just the Dock that hasn't quit. Finder & Safari are still running too. That might be a place to start investigating.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing some of the items from your dock?  You can always add them back later. Also go under your Apple Icon in the top left corner to the force quit option and see if there is a application open somewhere you're not aware and force quit it.  Finally, look in your system preferences for the Dock. You can choose to hide the Dock to only appear when your cursor goes to the bottom of the screen. I doubt that would solve your problem though.  I have my Dock on the left side of my screen and it is hidden, that way I can see the entire screen and only access the Dock when I need to open an application.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't see how any of this can help. Removing items from the dock shouldn't do anything. Since everything is closed except the dock, force quitting won't do anything (at least using the menu, `killall Dock` might work.) Hiding the dock is only visual and doesn't affect the process itself.

Comment: You say removing items shouldn't do anything, but I would think it's worth a try. I am only offering suggestions. I only suggested hiding in dock because it allows you to see the whole screen during operation. It was not a suggestion to solve your problem. Sorry for the confusion. Did you even check your force quit to make sure everything was down?  Sometimes I will have an application open that freezes or something, so I go to force quit and it says it is not responsive. So I have to force quit just shut it down.  Sorry I couldn't help.